# Problems processing ANSI txt file with space separated values

Tags: apex, visualforce, files

I have a requirement in which I have to process a txt file prompted by the user. These files are normal data files, with headers and values, the thing is , these txt files are ANSI (not UTF-8) so, on one hand, I have to find a way to solve that (I found a couple of solutions involving custom code for encoding to utf). For the time being and to test my code, I'm manually converting with Windows Notepad to UTF-8, but I can't force users to do that everytime before using my Visualforce.

Then the next thing is , there is no delimiter in between values, only spaces, and in a weird manner (some spaces bigger than others) and some headers that are two words also separated by spaces.

[image]

As you can see in the picture above, that is the space between headers.

[image]

Then in this one, there is a space between words inside the header.

I don't really know a lot about characters, encoding, ASCII and all that stuff. I did some file processing but always with CSV files and with specific delimiters, like commas.

I can split by line break correctly, and I get all the lines with the usual:

```
List<String> lines = fileString.split('\r\n');
```

But then, if I do this: `lines[0].split('');`, it splits in a weird way, with some headers stuck together, as if not every space is equal (which is what I assumed).

[image]

As you can see in the picture, the first three headers were treated as only one, even if there are spaces between them, and some headers are split in the middle because these are two words.

Is there a way to detect which specific characters are the ones that separate the header/values and which ones are just separating the words? Any help would be appreciated, I've never encountered this situation before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a Tab-Delimited Values (TSV) file. This format is nearly identical to CSV, except it uses `\t` instead of `,`. You can split it like this:

```
lines[0].split('\\t');
```

Comment: It certainly is. I thought they might be tabs but I didn't know a tab was a character on its own. Thank you.